# Como impedir que os dados sejam postados no google busca?

Tags: php, seo

Tenho um banco de dados. Dentro, uma database com os dados de várias pessoas. Tenho um sistema de agendamentos. Nele são colocados todos os dados da pessoa + dia/hora do agendamento.
O problema é que esses dados podem ser visualizados no google, se eu pesquisar o nome + nome do site.
Devo impedir o acesso dessa página restringindo o IP?
Quais os procedimentos que devo fazer?

Comment: Cara, esse tipo de informação não precisaria de um usuário e senha para ser acessada? você pode também usar o robots.txt para não indexar a página...

Comment: Denali, alguma resposta resolve o teu problema? É interessante você dar um feedback, pois outra pessoa pode ter o mesmo problema, e ao chegar aqui saberá o que foi feito. :) Veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) o que você pode fazer ao obter uma resposta para sua pergunta. ;)

Answer (score 4):

> **Editado**: Configurando apenas o robots.txt não removerá a sua página dos
>   índices do google.

- **Robots.txt:** Não permite que uma search engine receba o conteúdo de uma determinada página.
- **Meta tag robots:** Permite o acesso ao conteúdo, mas não permite a indexação deste conteúdo.

Resumindo, faça uso de ambas as técnicas, utilizando o `robots.txt` e a meta tag `robots`, mas se a página já estava indexada, é recomendado utilizar ainda a [Ferramenta do Google para Remoção de URLs](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/url-removal)

Fonte:

- [Arquivo robots.txt](http://www.agenciamestre.com/seo/robots-txt/)
- [Tag noindex](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=pt-BR)
- [Remover Página do Google](http://www.agenciamestre.com/artigos-premium/remover-pagina-do-google-metodos-e-implicacoes/)
- [Ferramenta Remover URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=pt-BR)

Comment: há como impedir que o site inteiro não entre no google busca? é só fazer isso? User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Disallow: http://www.meusite.com.br/

Comment: Usando "Disallow: /" irá desabilitar para todo o site. Da uma olhada aqui: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=pt-BR&ref_topic=6061961

Comment: fiz tais procedimentos, você tem alguma ideia de quanto tempo os dados somem da busca do google ?

Comment: @Denali. https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/faq#h18

Answer (score 4):

Use a seguinte meta tag HTML nas páginas que não devem ser indexados nos mecanismos de busca:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
```